# How to make mac to use emacs 26

Tags: macos, emacs

I installed emacs using `brew cask install emacs`

when I type

```
$ emacs
```

the emacs that opens still on version 22 instead of 26.

How can make my mac to use version 26?

**FYI**

In case anyone interested to open from command line, add below as your alias

`alias emacs='open -a /Applications/Emacs.app $1'`

Answer (score 2):

When you use cask, it should install it to your Applications folder, not the command line.  Check your Applications folder, it should be a stand alone program.